# How to use variables created multiple times by a loop in Activiti

Tags: loops, activiti

I am quite new to the activiti-bpm and allready having a problem I cant find any solution on the Internet. So our workflow looks like this:

[image: The activiti-snippet]

now the "Untersuchung dokumentieren" task creates two variables each time it is performed.

My first question is now: Does this mechanism create unique variables every time the task "Untersuchung dokumentieren" is performed or does it overried the exisiting variables.

My second question is: How do I access the so created variables (if it does create multiple variables)

Thanks in advance and have a greate day

Answer (score 1):

> My first question is now: Does this mechanism create unique variables every time the task "Untersuchung dokumentieren" is performed or does it overried the exisiting variables.

You can use the task local variable.
(ex)TaskService.setVariableLocal method.
https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/TaskService.html#setVariableLocal-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Because a new task is generated for each loop, the variables of the task are independent for each loop.

> My second question is: How do I access the so created variables (if it does create multiple variables)

You can access the task local variable by TaskService.getVariableLocal.
https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/TaskService.html#getVariableLocal-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-